# Changing default path of Hive Managed tables during cluster creation in HDInsight 4.0

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

I have an HDInsight (Hadoop) 4.0 cluster. Default path for Hive Managed tables is hive/warehouse/managed and it resides in the default storage account for the cluster. I would like the default hive managed path to point to an additional storage account that I have attached to the same cluster. The reason for this is that many times I may delete and recreate the cluster, and every time I have to delete the default container for the default storage account otherwise cluster creation will fail -- or specify a new container every time. It creates a tricky situation where managed tables created during earlier instantiations of the cluster keep pointing to old default containers. I know this can be prevented if we specify `LOCATION` explicitly during the managed table creation, but I just don't want to have anything residing in the default container even if `LOCATION` is omitted.I am trying to isolate data from cluster metadata which is what the default container is for. And I would like this to be done during cluster creation (not post cluster creation through Ambari). How do we achieve that? I haven't seen any such option in the cluster creation UI of Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the default path of the managed tables by creating HDInsight cluster using Azure Portal.

**Before creation of HDInsight Cluster:** If you want to modify before the cluster creation, you can use "Bootstrap scripts".

Bootstrap scripts allow you to install and configure components in Azure HDInsight programmatically.

There are three approaches to set configuration file settings as your HDInsight cluster is created:

- Use Azure PowerShell
- Use .NET SDK
- Use Azure Resource Manager template

For more details, refer "[Customize HDInsight clusters using Bootstrap scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-bootstrap)".

**After creation of HDInsight Cluster:**

You can add additional clusters to the Custom Metastore for Azure Portal as well as from Ambari configurations ( Hive -->Advanced).

[image]

**OR**

The default location for Hive managed tables is the hive warehouse.  The location of the hive warehouse is set by the hive.metastore.warehouse property in the **hive-site.xml** file:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/hive/warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this will only allow changing path, if you look at my post carefully you will see the reason why I need to do this -- I just don't want a different path, I rather need different path on a different storage (linked) -- because when I re-create (delete and create) a cluster , I delete the default container , because otherwise cluster creation fails. Otherwise every time I create new instance of the cluster, I have to maintain old default container that was created during last instantiation. So I want to isolate the metastore path from default storage. Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: As per my knowledge, you are not allowed to change the Hive warehouse from default storage to attached storage.

Comment: this is a problem, there has to be some solution -- otherwise every time you re-create a cluster you have to manually migrate all the managed table data to new storage which might not be feasible if the size is huge. And external table might not be the solution if you are specifically interested in managed tables only -- which is a valid use case, at if one is interested in ACID tables in Hive 3 ACID is only supported for managed tables in Hive 3.